# Как подключить динамическую библиотеку в Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qtcreator, библиотеки

Пока гуглил этот вопрос, натыкался на огромное количество вопросов подобного рода. Но все пишут про статические библиотеки. То есть людям говорят в `.pro` файле прописать:

```
LIBS += "path\to\library.lib"
```

И все. И почему-то никак не могу найти как подключить именно динамическую `.dll` библиотеку. Может кто-то объяснить? Моя библиотека состоит из `.lib`, `.h` и `.dll` файлов и была создана в VS 2019. Теперь я хочу ее подключить к Qt Creator

Comment: .dll нужна при выполнении приложения, а не при сборке. Для линковки нужна именно библиотека импорта .lib

Comment: @user7860670 то есть достаточно просто указать `.lib` файл и бросить `.dll` в корень проекта? А как же заголовочные файлы? И как система поймет, как `.lib` связан с `.dll`?